# IDA How to set variables type with name which have angle brackets in local types name?

Tags: c++, variables, types, ida

IDA local types has a local type like:

```
struct DEMOTYPE<int>
{
_DWORD dw1;
_DWORD dw2;
}
```

how to use "DEMOTYPE"(C++  type) just like normal c type? press Y can not Can't achieve the goal since the "<>" in it.

i know if the target is function,we can change the function declaration with its  mangled name.

In a word, how can we use the c++ type declaration in the local types to change the type of the local variable?

Below is the code I tried, but the F5 pseudocode view cannot be changed.

```
def setVarType(lvname, lti, isptr=False):
    addr = idc.here()
    c = idaapi.decompile(addr)
    for v in c.lvars:
        if v.name == lvname:
            print("find target variable：", v.name)
            idati = ida_typeinf.get_idati()
            ti = ida_typeinf.tinfo_t()
            if ti.get_numbered_type(idati, lti):
                print("find local type：", lti, ":", ti)
                if isptr:
                    ti_ptr = ida_typeinf.tinfo_t()
                    ti_ptr.create_ptr(ti)  # ti_ptr = ti *
                    bret = v.set_final_lvar_type(ti_ptr)
                else:
                    bret = v.set_final_lvar_type(ti)
                print(bret)
```

Comment: What you are looking at is a class (struct) template and is perfectly normal C++ (and used a lot). Maybe this will help you understand a bit more https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates. (It can also be I totally did not understand your real question ;) )

Comment: I known templates,i want to know just is there any way  make ida recognize the  type declaration  "DEMOTYPE<int>" which already exist in local types and it's memory layout already  known.  if the local types name changed to "DEMOTYPEint" then ida can recognize it, but i don't want to change the name since there is too many  such types like that.I think the key point is the angle brackets, a similar problem: to make ida support Chinese function names, you can use hook ida.dll to prevent it from replacing Chinese characters with "_".

Comment: `struct DEMOTYPE<int>` creates an new type with a unique name - implementation dependent.  You will need to find a way to get the compiler to tell you the generated (internal) name.   The name `DEMOTYPE<int>` does not exist after compilation.

Comment: I had to lookup what IDA does, and it clearly states :  It cannot parse templates and other complex constructs but simple standard cases can be parsed. (https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1691.shtml ). Afaik There is no way to convert a template struct to a non-template one.  Aliasing (e.g. using DEMOTYPE_INT = DEMOTYPE<int>) or deriving from it will still result in a preprocessor having to parse the template.

Comment: Richard's idea may be right. If i can find the internal name , i can solve it, or ida checked and filtered "<" during a certain process, which caused the Y function to not be successfully applied.
I tried to use set_lvar_type successfully, but this does not change   .idb file. Although the mouse prompt type has been changed, I did not find a way to refresh it to pseudo code.
What I need is to change the type of local variables in the pseudocode window (similar to press Y ).

Comment: This question has become much more relevant with IDA7.7 which **can** process templated types (via clang), but still won't let you do anything with them afterwards.  I don't buy that it has anything to do with the requirement to parse them, as they have already been parsed, and the `<` and `>` are just characters in the type name. _p.s., you **can** change a typename to have `<` or `>` in it by using the structure view and `N`_

Comment: A few days after I asked the question, I solved the problem myself and submitted the key information to solve the problem as an answer, unfortunately this answer was marked for deletion, the reason I did not provide the specific complete code but the key information It's my hope that someone like me who encounters this problem can finally solve it on their own. I am submitting again as a comment the key information to solve this problem (IDA SDK - Rename Variable permanently: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18063/ida-sdk-rename-variable-permanently)

Comment: @omgkaka Ahh, I am familiar with that answer, though I can't see how it helps as it about changing names, not types. However, I have since written an idapython function that changes both (or either), and appears to allow changing of variable types to template-ish values.

Comment: @Orwellophile  name is property, type is also a property,the url link show how to change the name.so.......then use modify_user_lvar_info save the changed info to idb.

Answer (score 1):

This one really drove me up the walls... I even put a lot of work into a simplified GCC mangler and made an IDA plugin for refactoring that mangles your name. In the end, it turns out none of that was needed. From what I have gathered, IDA's netnodes can use ANY character except `\0`. All you need to do is open IDA_INSTALL_DIR/cfg/ida.cfg and add your desired characters to NameChars like so

```
NameChars = "~`.:<>?!/,()[]" // Add special characters for C++/Swift
        "$?@"                // asm specific character
        "_0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
        // This would enable common Chinese characters in identifiers:
        // Block_CJK_Unified_Ideographs,
        CURRENT_CULTURE;
```

And voila, now you can name functions and variables using the characters `` ~`.:<>?!/,()[] ``

IDA will automatically represent most characters as `_`, however; luckily `<>` are properly represented.

Example renaming a function with angle brackets:
[image: Example renaming a function with angle brackets]

This will work for most things, but not local types. If you need to rename structs using special characters, you'll need to edit TypeNameChars as well, like so:

```
// the following characters are allowed in type names.

TypeNameChars = "~.<>?!/," // Add special characters for C++/Swift
        "_:$()`'{}"
        "_0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

And now we can use `~.<>?!/,` in type names!

Example renaming a Swift struct to have a period:
[image: Example renaming a Swift struct to have a period]

Additionally, using `.` requires extra consideration. See the comment by arizvisa on github that lead me to this fix:
[image: arizvisa's comment]
https://github.com/idapython/src/issues/56#issuecomment-1837279243

Comment: Does this allow you to add structs via Local Types that contain `<>` et al, or only through the Structures panel?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, though only for local variables (not for function arguments).

Typical usage: `set_lvar_name_type(here(), 'v1', None, 'rage::atArray<int>')`

```py
def set_lvar_name_type(ea, src, name, t, vu=None):
    """
    Change the name or type of a local variable

    @param ea: address of function
    @param src: current name of variable
    @param name: new name (or None to leave as is)
    @param t: new type (str, tinfo_t, or None to leave as is)
    @param v: handle to existing pseudocode window (vdui_t, or None)

    @note
    Will not work with function arguments or global variables
    """
    # m = [ea for ea in [pprev(ea, 1) for ea in l if GetFuncName(ea)] if ea]
    def get_tinfo_elegant(name):
        ti = ida_typeinf.tinfo_t()
        til = ti.get_til()
        # get_named_type(self, til, name, decl_type=BTF_TYPEDEF, resolve=True, try_ordinal=True)
        if ti.get_named_type(til, name, ida_typeinf.BTF_STRUCT, True, True):
            return ti
        return None

    def get_pseudocode_vu(ea, vu=None):
        func = idaapi.get_func(ea)
        if func:
            return idaapi.open_pseudocode(func.start_ea, 0)

    if isinstance(t, str):
        tif = get_tinfo_elegant(t)
        if not tif:
            raise ValueError("Couldn't get tinfo_t for type '{}'".format(t))
        t = tif
    elif isinstance(t, ida_typeinf.tinfo_t) or t is None:
        pass
    else:
        raise TypeError("Unknown type for t '{}'".format(type(t)))

    vu = get_pseudocode_vu(ea, vu)
    if vu:
        lvars = [n for n in vu.cfunc.lvars if n.name == src]
        if len(lvars) == 1:
            print("changing name/type of {}/{} to {}/{}".format(lvars[0].name, lvars[0].type(), name, str(t)))
            if t:
                vu.set_lvar_type(lvars[0], t)
            if name:
                vu.rename_lvar(lvars[0], name, 1)
        else:
            print("[set_lvar_name_type] couldn't find var {}".format(src))
    return False
```